# Having trouble with list.push_back and std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

This little snippet is giving me quite some trouble. I just can't figure out what is wrong with it:

```
m_buttons.push_back(
  std::shared_ptr<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<ShinyButton>, BUTTONTYPE>>(
    std::make_pair(
      std::shared_ptr<ShinyButton>(new ShinyButton(0, 0, 0, 0, "menue_1", "menue_1_glow", 55, 55, 7, 7)),
      START
    )
  )
);
```

the list has the following definition:

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<ShinyButton>,BUTTONTYPE>>>
```

The Error given from the compiler is:

> No constructer matches Argument list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to initialise a `std::shared_ptr<std::pair<X, Y>>` with `std::make_pair`. That is like initialising an `int *` with an `int`. Perhaps you meant to use `make_shared`:

```
m_buttons.push_back(
  std::make_shared<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<ShinyButton>, BUTTONTYPE>>(
    std::make_pair(
      std::shared_ptr<ShinyButton>(new ShinyButton(0, 0, 0, 0, "menue_1", "menue_1_glow", 55, 55, 7, 7)),
      START
    )
  )
);
```

In fact, with `make_shared`, you won't even need the `make_pair` call:

```
m_buttons.push_back(
  std::make_shared<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<ShinyButton>, BUTTONTYPE>>(
    std::shared_ptr<ShinyButton>(new ShinyButton(0, 0, 0, 0, "menue_1", "menue_1_glow", 55, 55, 7, 7)),
    START
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the return `make_pair` which is a `pair` and not a `pair*`.  You can use:

```
std::make_shared<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<ShinyButton>,BUTTONTYPE>>(
    std::make_pair(
        std::make_shared<ShinyButton>(0, 0, 0, 0, "menue_1", "menue_1_glow", 55, 55, 7, 7), START
    )
);
```